Error When Send Test Message through Whatsapp cloud api
I am getting this error when click on Send Message In API setup section (Sending of message failed.
There was a problem with the access token or permissions you are using for the API call) [First Issue]
Its working perfect few hours ago facing problem after creating a new Facebook business profile in same Facebook profile and verified it and other thing i do is add a new number in meta business suite, and in my other business profile i unable to add phone number for onboarding.
getting this error in second profile
There was a problem registering your phone number
This page is not available right now. Please try reloading in a few minutes. (Second Issue)
is there anybody who face this problem or have any solution for this.

Sorry guys for mistake Second image was first issue and first image as for second issue

Not sure what exactly you are asking here, but as long as it says "There was a problem registering your phone number" right on top there, I suppose you must probably not expect sending messages via that number(?) is going to work.

Many are reporting the same issue in the Meta community and also reporting missing flows. Looks like a temporary outage.

We are facing the same problem here.

this issue was with temporary token but now it has been resolved.

Please [edit] and provide details, especially on how to make use of that knowledge to solve the problem. Or was it server side and nobody needs to change/do anything to have the symptoms disappear? In that case please state that clearly in the answer, which I then consider a helpful answer.
